# Current.User.Identity is empty when web service is calling another web service

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, iis-6, .net-2.0

I am troubled with the following case:

I have a web service (this is ancient runes. .NET 2.0, asmx-file) written i C#. When the service is being called the user is checked with HttpContext.Current.User etc. And the call needs to be done with an Active Directory account. There is no problem at all getting the current users identiy with this.

The thing is that this web service calls another web service at some point but in the second web service the Current.User.Identity-object is empty!?

Why is this and how do i fix it?

Both the services are hosted on Server 2003 with IIS 6. Both services are running on ApplicationPools that have enabled Windows Authentication.

Comment: Are the web services located on different machines?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell with limited descriptions of ancient runes, but I'd guess the 1st service is setup to require authentication whereas the 2nd service is not. So the first thing to look at is if the 2nd service is allowing anonymous connections and if so disabling that and it could work out.

In general this is not a great way to secure a web service, even an ancient ASMX one.

Comment: The second service does and needs to allow anonymous connections. Why is this not a great way to secure a web service?

Comment: What you are running into here -- too easy to have something insecure due to infrastructure issues. Better off having it baked in by doing something like requiring soap headers. Or getting into WS-* if you need more formalized arrangements. Why does the 2nd service need to allow anonymous access if it is supposed to be secured?

Comment: I havnt wrote the 2nd service myself. Originally it only had methods that was getters. The service was only for getting some data, not manipulating data at all so someone decided long ago to allow anonymous access. Now a demand has come that the second service should have a method for setting some specific data and for that one needs to be a specific access level (which is linked to the AD-account) and the first service needs to be extended with a method that by some point needs to use the new method in the second one.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your anwsers, i really appreciate your help. This is an old system that needs to be reviewed. But that wont happen soon.